# Ignore null property when converting to JSON

Tags: jquery, json, asmx

I have a question which seemed to be an easy one but turns out as a really hard one.

I wrote something like this

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
// To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class UIService : System.Web.Services.WebService
{

public UIService () {

    //Uncomment the following line if using designed components 
    //InitializeComponent(); 
}


[WebMethod(EnableSession=true)]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
[System.Security.Permissions.PrincipalPermission(System.Security.Permissions.SecurityAction.Demand, Authenticated = true)]
public Accordion ConstructAccordian(string accordionId)
{
    Accordion result = new Accordion();
    result.Name = "MenuAccordion";
    AccordionItem item1 = new AccordionItem("Test");
    item1.Items.Add(new MenuItem("User", "UserList"));
    item1.Items.Add(new MenuItem("OnlineUser", "OnlineUser"));        
    result.Items.Add(item1);

    return result;

}


function get(url, pdata, func) {
var msg = "Exception";

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: url,
    data: JSON.stringify(pdata),
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
    success: function (data, textStatus) {
        if (textStatus == "success") {

            if (data.hasOwnProperty('d')) {
                msg = data.d;

            } else {
                msg = data;
            }
            func(msg);
        }

    },
    error: function (data, textStatus) {
        get(MEMBERSHIP_SERVICE_AUTHCHCK_URL, {}, function (msg) {
            if (msg.error == true) {
                window.location = PORTAL_LOGIN_URL;
            }
            else {
                get(url, pdata, func);
            }
        });
    }
});
}
```

It works fine. But when a property in an accordion in null. that property appears in JSON string and the value of it is null. I want JavaScriptSerializer, which is used by System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService, ignores null properties and therefore not generate them in json string. I searched a lot and I think JavaScriptSerializer can not do this. Is there a simple way to change JavaScriptSerializer and for example use JSON.net instead as default formmater for ScriptService or how can I ignore generating null properties when serializing to JSON.

Comment: Never used it but you could research about creating a custom converter to see if that helps. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.registerconverters.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. Use C# library from http://json.org/ to convert object to json string
2. From the server send json string.
3. At the client side use var obj = $.parseJSON(jsonString);